# notification with the enclosed Application

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, httprequest

I wanted to know how to trigger notification when the application is closed.
For example, notification of Clash of Clan when that one is attacked.
Even if my application is closed (by the user), I still want to receive the notification.
In addition, it is possible to trigger with an HTTP request ?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't follow what you're even trying to describe. Please re-word your scenario and be clear about the details so we know what you're trying to accomplish. All I see here are words like email notification, which I don't know if you're currently receiving one or not receiving one, and whether that you do want to receive such emails or don't. Also words like "close" are you referring to the application erroring, or the user manually closing the application? An HTTP Request to where? To the game? To your server? An email?

Comment: I change, I do not know if you understand better ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to trigger notifications they way you want to and when the application is closed you need to implent apple push notification service. Please have a look here:
[APN's](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html)

Comment: Thank you ! I'll go see this.

Comment: have a good look at this and you can alway refer to the apple manual.It has tons of information. anything you might need feel free to ask here

Comment: Thank you, I am well informed in the manual, but I ended up giving up because you have an account developper. Unfortunately, I do not have the money to take me. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I don't have a paid developer account yet but i might start one soon. You could find a real life friend and create one together for 99$. Your call :)

Comment: yes it's true, but I know no one who code on Xcode ... ^^